# There was and error downloading 'https://$metadata'. The request failed with http status 403: Forbidden - XAMARIN WEB REFERENCE WITH HTTPS

Tags: web-services, wcf, ssl, iis, xamarin.android

I managed to create a web `service` with self signed `SSL` through `IIS`. It's settings at first are set to Client Certificate to none and none required `SSL`. It is accessible by that time threw web browser and mobile web reference.

**Web Browser**
[image: Web Service Host Running]

**Xamarin Web Reference**
[image]

But when I set the SSL settings to required, it is now forbidden in both. What am I missing in settings for SSL Configuration?

**SSL Settings Thru IIS**
[image: SSL Settings set to required]

**Web Browser Forbidden Access**
[image: Web Browser Error]

**Xamarin Web Reference Forbidden Access**
[image: Web Reference Error]

**WebConfig**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="constring" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source = source;Initial Catalog = dbname; User ID = user; Password = pw" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation targetFramework="4.5" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding maxReceivedMessageSize="10485760" name="SecureHttpBinding">
          <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="10485760"></readerQuotas>
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None"></transport>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>    
    </bindings>

    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I didn't try it, but did you see this part: [Using Transport Security](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/web_services/#Using_Transport_Security)?

Comment: No, this is my first time to see it and thanks for it. May I ask where should I put those code?

Comment: Try this tutorial: [UsingTrustedRootsRespectfully](http://www.mono-project.com/archived/usingtrustedrootsrespectfully/).

Comment: I already found the answer. Thanks for the link but it seems that it is not the answer I am looking for xamarin.android web reference

Answer (score 0):

To access web service via HTTPS in web browser, I followed [this link for creating temporary client certificate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650751.aspx) but I changed the step #5 to this command

```
makecert -sk MyKeyName -iv RootCaClientTest.pvk -n "CN=tempClientcert" -ic RootCaClientTest.cer -sr localmachine -ss my -sky exchange -pe
```

I changed the **currentuser** to ***localmachine*** and **signature** to ***exchange*** so that it will be in personal certificate store. When you access the site again, it will ask for client certificate and you can choose it to proceed.

For the main problem to access the service in visual studio xamarin via web reference (which is forbidden somehow).
I found [this link to solve the forbidden problem](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b884f7f3-10c2-43df-bfb9-1e53a247efaf/cannot-add-reference-to-ssl-wcf-service-from-specific-machine?forum=wcf). You can see the second post of (c)MarkoOkram for the solution.

"I am  solved problem by saving web browser .wsdl and .xsd files on file system, change reference in those files to matching files. Than i succesfully add reference in visual studio to that file system .wsdl file." *-(c) MarkoOkram*

I downloaded the file WSDL and XSDs written in WSDL then retarget the filepath to their respective directories and it's done.

update: I also tried to import singleWSDL and it works without editing for xsd's

Comment: But there is a new problem . Connection refused :( . System.Net.WebException: Error: ConnectFailure (Connection refused) ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Connection refused